# How do I use LitJson to edit single attributes of multiple instances of one class all stored in one json file?

Tags: c#, json, class, unity-game-engine, litjson

I am trying to create an inventory system using a json file. Basically, I have my json file:

```
[
    {
    "name":"Potion",
    "id":1,
    "balance":5
    },
    {
    "name":"Neutral Bomb",
    "id":2,
    "balance": 4
    }
]
```

And I have my c# file:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using LitJson;


public class Item
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public int Id       { get; set; }
    public int Balance  { get; set; }

    public Item(string name1, int id1, int balance1) {
        Name = name1;
        Id = id1;
        Balance = balance1;
    }
}

public class InventoryAttempt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void BalanceChange(string filePath, int ID, int change)
    {
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + filePath);
        List<Item> itemList = JsonMapper.ToObject<List<Item>>(jsonString);
        itemList [ID].Balance += change;
        jsonString = JsonMapper.ToJson (itemList).ToString();
        File.WriteAllText (Application.dataPath + filePath, jsonString);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        BalanceChange ("/Scripts/inventory.json", 1, 1);
    }
}
```

In my c# file I want to access a single item, lets say the neutral bomb item. How can I go in and edit the balance of the neutral bomb? I want to use the Item ID to tell which object to edit. I want to create a list where each element is one of the items that are stored in the Json file, but I'm not sure how to separate them. What should I do?

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Default constructor not found...ctor() of Item'.
System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:368)
System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:254)
LitJson.JsonMapper.ReadValue (System.Type inst_type, LitJson.JsonReader reader)
LitJson.JsonMapper.ReadValue (System.Type inst_type, LitJson.JsonReader reader)
LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject[List`1] (System.String json)
InventoryAttempt.BalanceChange (System.String filePath, Int32 ID, Int32 change) (at Assets/Scripts/InventoryAttempt.cs:26)
InventoryAttempt.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/InventoryAttempt.cs:34)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit JSON values in c# with LitJson in Unity3D?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165004/how-do-i-edit-json-values-in-c-sharp-with-litjson-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the variable names in your Json does not match the ones in your `Item` class. The ones in your `Item` class are capitalized.

Use Unity's [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html).

Secondly, get the `JsonHelper` class from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3785314) post. It allows Unity's [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) to serialize and deserialize Json Array.

Do **not** generate Json by hand in the future since you will run into problems like this. Use the Json class and a simple function to do that. For example, this:

```
void generateJson()
{
    Item[] item = new Item[2];

    item[0] = new Item();
    item[0].Name = "Potion";
    item[0].Id = 1;
    item[0].Balance = 5;

    item[1] = new Item();
    item[1].Name = "Neutral Bomb";
    item[1].Id = 2;
    item[1].Balance = 4;

    string value = JsonHelper.ToJson(item, true);
    Debug.Log(value);
}
```

Will generate this:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "Name": "Potion",
            "Id": 1,
            "Balance": 5
        },
        {
            "Name": "Neutral Bomb",
            "Id": 2,
            "Balance": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

No error. That is valid json.

**Solution**:

`InventoryAttempt` class:

```
public class InventoryAttempt
{
    public static void BalanceChange(string filePath, int ID, int change)
    {
        //Load Data
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + filePath);

        Item[] item = JsonHelper.FromJson<Item>(jsonString);

        //Loop through the Json Data Array
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
        {
            //Check if Id matches
            if (item[i].Id == ID)
            {
                Debug.Log("Found!");
                //Increment Change value?
                item[i].Balance += change;
                break; //Exit loop
            }
        }

        //Convert to Json
        string newJsonString = JsonHelper.ToJson(item);

        //Save
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + filePath, newJsonString);
    }
}
```

Your `Item` class `Item`.

```
[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
    public int Balance;

    public Item()
    {

    }

    public Item(string name1, int id1, int balance1)
    {
        Name = name1;
        Id = id1;
        Balance = balance1;
    }
}
```

Test script:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        InventoryAttempt.BalanceChange("/Scripts/inventory.json", 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Note:

I removed get/set property stuff. Please remove these as they must be removed for this to work. Also, `[Serializable]` is added to the top of the `Item` class. Please add that as-well. *I suggest you copy and replace the classes directly before making the "it doesn't work" comment under the question*...

Answer (score 0):

First things first your json does not seem to be a valid array (not the missing `[` and `]`.

```
[
    {
        "name":"Potion"
        "id":1,
        "balance":7
    },
    {
        "name":"Neutral Bomb",
        "id":2,
        "balance": 4
    }
]
```

Also, I would follow naming conventions and start the properties with an Upper Case characters.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public int Id       { get; set; }
    public int Balance  { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
    }

    public Item(string name1, int id1, int balance1)
    {
        Name = name1;
        Id = id1;
        Balance = balance1;
    }
}
```

The code below should give you want you want, but depending on the scope of your project could be very inefficient. You may want to consider caching the `jsonString` and/or the deserialization result.  You may also want to use FirstOrDefault and use a null check if its expected the ID may not exist.

```
public class InventoryAttempt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Item JsonToItem(string filePath, int itemID)
    {
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + filePath);
        return JsonMapper.ToObject<List<Item>>(jsonString).First(x => x.Id == itemID);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        var item = JsonToItem("/Scripts/inventory.json", 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The .First thing wont work. It shows up red and doesn't work. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I changed the script based mostly on what you said, but without the .First() because it created a bunch of errors. What do I do to make this code work?

Comment: For First() you are likely just missing the `using System.Linq` statement.

Comment: I also updated the `First()` statement in the code above.  Should be something like `.First(x => x.Id == itemID)`.

Comment: Will this allow me to edit the item and then put it back into the json file?

Comment: I tried what you said, but it still gives me the error. I pasted the error at the bottom of my question. Any idea why that is? Is ToObject<List<Item>>() even a possible function?

Comment: I do not see the error at the bottom of your question.

Comment: You're right, I must not have finished the edit. My bad.

Comment: I put it there now

Comment: You are missing the default parameterless constructor for the class `Item`.

Comment: I updated my post to show the `Item` class with a parameterless constructor.

Comment: InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
System.Linq.Enumerable.First[Item] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate, Fallback fallback)
System.Linq.Enumerable.First[Item] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate)
InventoryAttempt.JsonToItem (System.String filePath, Int32 itemID) (at Assets/Scripts/InventoryAttempt.cs:38)
InventoryAttempt.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/InventoryAttempt.cs:42)

Comment: I am done for the day.  If you are still stuck tomorrow, let me know.  I can whip up a sample application for you.